# Ejecutar comando Linux en PHP da error "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Tags: php, linux

Estoy intentando reiniciar un servicio de Linux, pero no me funciona.

Tengo este trozo de codigo sacado de la web:

```
<form action="reset.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Reiniciar" class="button" >
</form>
```

Y este es el `reset.php`:

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec("service garen restart");

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Cuando le doy al boton para ejecutar el `reset.php`, se queda en blanco y no ejecuta el comando.

Si añado `sudo` al comando tampoco me funciona y el log indica:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: Hola Fran, bienvenido a [es.so]. Parece que tu pregunta está cortada.. puedes [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74295/edit) para acabar de explicar tu problema? ^^  No olvides leer el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: Probablemente no funcione por necesitar permisos de `sudo`?

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara Con sudo tambien lo he probado y nada, sigue igual.

Comment: ¿Qué te dice el log del sistema? ¿No puedes recoger el resultado de `shell_exec()`? Probablemente tienes que poner al usuario apache o www en el sudoers.

Comment: Por favor lee las notas del manual de PHP : http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php y prueba a usarlo con otro comando más sencillo como el que pone el manual. ¿Si ejecutas el comando que estás intentando directamente devuelve algo?

Comment: @fedorqui El log me dice: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, he probrado un "echo" y si me lo devuelve.

Comment: No me refiero a echo sino a escribir solamente esto en línea de comandos : `service garen restart` ¿devuelve algo ? Si no devuelve nada o da error cuando lo usas con shell_exec no verás nada en pantalla.

Comment: Al necesitar sudo puede ser que te falte el password luego?

Comment: @A.Cedano En la pantalla del navegador sale una pagina en blanco, el servicio sigue sin reiniciarse y en el log no pone nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El sistema te está diciendo:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Esto quiere decir que `sudo` quiere mostrarte un prompt donde pedirte la contraseña... ¡pero no tiene donde hacerlo porque no se está ejecutando en un entorno donde lo haya!

Por tanto, vayamos al origen del problema: el usuario que quieres que ejecute el comando `sudo service garen restart` no tiene permisos para hacerlo o al menos directamente sin contraseña, de ahí que la pida.
Lo que hay que hacer es darle permisos en el *sudoers* y hacerlo de manera que no pida la contraseña.

Suponiendo que estás trabajando con Apache y su usuario es *apache*, deberías abrir el sudoers con `visudo` y añadir una línea del tipo:

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service garen restart
```

Donde `/usr/sbin/service` puede variar según tu sistema pues es la ruta completa de `service`. Para obtenerla, escribe `which service`.

Comment: Esa linea que me ofreces añadir al sudoers, dice que esta mal, y que da error...

Comment: @Fran será porque tenemos que poner toda la ruta de `service`. En mi caso, `/usr/sbin/service`. Puedes obtenerla escribiendo `which service`.

Comment: Vale, eso si funciona... Muchas gracias :D Te marco el tick de que me lo has solucionado :D

Comment: @Fran ¡qué bien! Bienvenido a [es.so], esperamos verte de nuevo :)